# Dictionary values in React props (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-props

Given a component Product with a props interface ProductProps defined:

```
interface ProductProps {
  name: string,
  price: {
    amount: number,
    currency: string
  }
}
```

how do I assign the values for `price` in the component tag i.e. I want something to the effect of:

```
<Product name="Nice Shoes" price.amount={100} price.currency="$" />
```

Comment: Just use an object literal. `<Product name="Nice Shoes" price={{amount :100, currency:"$"}} />`

Comment: Thanks. Gave up too quickly when I tried something similar and left out one set of braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because price is an object too you could pass like so:

```
<Product name="Nice Shoes" price={{amount :100, currency:"$"}} />
```

The first set of parenthesis are for the jsx syntax and the second is for the object itself

Comment: Thanks. Gave up too quickly when I tried something similar and left out one set of braces.

Comment: Your welcome, don't worry happens to all of us :)